# ListView ItemDataBound - determine if item is AlternatingItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemdatabound

I'm using the Listview to display my data. On the ItemDatabound event I want to do some manipulation and change some of the data being displayed. When I check the Item on this event I am using the following code, But I need to know if the item is an alternating item as this will effect what I want to do with the row. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
   ListViewDataItem currentItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
   DataKey currentDataKey = myLilstView.DataKeys[currentItem.DataItemIndex];

   //Do something   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see if this works:

```
int currentIndex = currentItem.DisplayIndex;
if (currentIndex % 2 == 1)
{
    // alternating item
}
```

Comment: You should use the *DisplayIndex* property instead of *DataItemIndex* if this list view is using paging from MSDN: "DisplayIndex represents the position of the data item in the current page, whereas DataItemIndex is based on the page offset"